# How do I Change The Position of a JLabel in a JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager

So Im making a Mafia Game in Eclipse using JFrame - andI want to set the location of the text in a JFrame.

Whenever I use the setPositionX and setPositionY it doesnt work!

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you post the code you've tried? That will helps us help you.

Comment: Show what you have tried.

Comment: Layout managers, layout properties, margins and empty borders

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't place components with absolute coordinates.

You study the concept of [layout managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/layoutlist.html). Then you decide which type of manager best supports your ideas.

And then you let that manager do the positioning of all UI elements. Anything else is basically a waste of time.

Meaning: of course you can position components "manually" using absolute values (see [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/none.html) for instructions how to do that).

But there is a **big** problem with that: you spend a lot of time to perfectly tune your components. And then you remember: "maybe I have to allow my users to resize the window". And then most of work turns useless; as you quickly figure: "when people resize the frame, I want this part to grow/shrink with it; whereas that part should stay put".

Long story short: absolute positioning only works for fixed resolution, fixed window size, fixed font size, fixed everything. Basically it fixes you into some corner - and getting out of that corner is *hard*.

So simply avoid that; and learn how to use one (or *several*) layout manager to do all that tedious work for you.

Answer (score -2):

```
Insets insets = panel.getInsets();
Dimension size =test.getPreferredSize();

// Just replace 10 & 0 according to X & Y position you want
test.setBounds(10 + insets.left, 0 + insets.top, size.width, size.height);
```